# node-gyp build error java module

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, npm, node-gyp

I'm getting troubles trying to install JAVA module in my NodeJS app. 
I'm working on Ubuntu:

- **NodeJS:** v6.2.0
- **NPM:** 3.8.9
- **Node-gyp:** v3.3.1
- **Pyhton:** 2.7.12
- **GCC:** 5.4.0

And I get all these errors trying `npm install`:

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/nsanz/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/nsanz/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/node" "/home/nsanz/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/nsanz/Documentos/projects/node-parse-tgd/node_modules/java
gyp ERR! node -v v6.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/nsanz/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/node" "/home/nsanz/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! java@0.6.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.6.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the java package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs java
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls java
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/nsanz/Documentos/projects/node-parse-tgd/npm-debug.log
```

I've tried to reinstall node-gyp and build-essentials already, but still cannot install JAVA module.

Comment: Have you checked that the Java SDK and compiler (javac) are installed and in the path of the current user? (Use `which javac` and you should see a path to a compiler binary show up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've seen this when java was included with version "^0.6.0". Increasing this to 0.7.0 or better solved the problem.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/10289